# Continuity of complex square root function

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$, we can write the function in polar form:

$$f(r,\theta)=\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}$$

where $r\geq 0$ and $0\leq\theta<2\pi$. Find the set

$$F=\text{the set of all discontinuities of }f$$

Most references I looked say that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}-\{z\in\mathbb{R}:z\leq 0\}$.

However, I have some trouble: let $z=r,z_n=re^{(2\pi-1/n)i}$, then $z_n\to z$,but

$$f(z_n)=\sqrt{r}e^{(\pi-\frac{1}{2n})i}\to\sqrt{r}e^{\pi i}=-\sqrt{r}\neq f(z)$$

which shows that $f$ is not continuous at $z=r>0$, which is a contradiction.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'problem' is the due to the definition of the argument $\theta$. I found two sources:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Principal_value
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexArgument.html

reminding that the argument of a complex number has principal value in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$. This moves the problem, that you adressed, to the negative real axis rather than the positive:
$$
f(r e^{-\pi+\tfrac{1}{n}})\rightarrow \sqrt r e^{-\tfrac{\pi}{2}}\neq \sqrt r e^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}}=f(-r)
$$

Just as a funny addition to this: if the argument was taken in $(-\frac{2\pi}{3},\frac{4\pi}{3}]$ the discontinuity would appear on the half-line $y=x$ for $x\leq 0$ and the complex numbers $z=x+iy$ lying on this line.

Comment: This makes sense. So does that mean the discontinuity depends on the domain of $\theta$?

Comment: Indeed! The usual square root defined on $\mathbb R^+$ is only WELL defined because the choice $\sqrt{x}\geq 0$ has been made. It could just as well have been $\sqrt{x}\leq 0$. And in $\mathbb C$ we have even more choices since we have another dimension and infinitely many new directions to point the discontinuity in.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now everything is perfectly clear.